# Are there any ansible module(s) to manage OpenStack Load-balancers (OpenStack LBaas)?

Tags: load-balancing, openstack, ansible, openstack-neutron

I want to define a pool in Openstack LBaas (Load Balancer as a Service) and then assign a VIP to it in order to create a Load-Balance cluster of servers. I want to automate this things using Ansible. I am looking for Ansbile modules that could help achieve the required thing.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible don't provide a [core module for Neutron](http://docs.ansible.com/list_of_cloud_modules.html) management yet and it doesn't appear on the [openstack-ansible](https://github.com/openstack-ansible/openstack-ansible) github project.

Checking the [TODO](https://github.com/openstack-ansible/openstack-ansible/blob/master/TODO.md) for the openstack-ansible project shows that they are still planning on working on adding Neutron LBaas configuration.

Answer (score 0):

**Ansible 2.7 now provides what you need if you have Octavia installed and enabled on your OpenStack Cloud**

> Add/Delete load balancer from OpenStack Cloud:
>   https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/os_loadbalancer_module.html#os-loadbalancer-module
>
> Add/Delete a listener for a load balancer from OpenStack Cloud
>   https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/os_listener_module.html#os-listener-module
>
> Add/Delete a pool in the load balancing service from OpenStack Cloud
>   https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/os_pool_module.html#os-pool-module